how can i replace next image src when it get 403 error?
I just found a bug in my React Component with next js Image component.
My image src in URL gets 403 status, i.e. error for access denied and image wasn't loaded. So I added onError method to this component as below:
<Image onError={({ currentTarget }) => {
                            currentTarget.onerror = null;
                            currentTarget.src = `/img/sources/${publisher.account_type}.png`;
                        }}
       width={32}
       height={32}
       src={getImage(publisher)}
       alt={publisher.name}
       className="h-8 w-8 min-w-8 rounded-full object-cover "
/>

but it still gives 403 error in infinite loop and does not replace new source in error event handler.
When I add "unoptimized=true" to Image component the issue is resolved.
Why does this happen and is there any other solution for handling img src giving HTTP status 403 error?

Error Description

maybe If you import and use an external library image, a 403 error will occur. So, the Next.js official document says that when importing an external image, you can write the domains in next.config.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#domains
module.exports = {
   images: {
   domains: ['assets.acme.com'],
   },
}

